# List order count on data table in view in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I've been looking around for a solution to a problem I'm facing and found related solutions but nothing that's quite right as of yet.

I have a Rails 3.2.9 app that has over 100,000 rows of data in table called Mentions. Mentions are snapshots of tweets that have been catalogued against certain subjects which are recorded as `event_types`. Simplified version of the table structure:

```
    create_table "mentions", :force => true do |t|
        t.integer  "event_id"
        t.string   "event_type"
        t.string   "event_name"
        t.integer  "source_author_follower_count"
        t.integer  "impressions"
        end
```

What I'm trying to do is create a table in a view that contains an ordered list of unique `event_name` instances sorted by the number of times rows with the same `event_name` occurred in the database along with the sum of each instances `source_author_follower_count` and `impressions` fields.

So the end result would look like:

```
    Event ID     Number Occurrences    Reach    Impressions

    event 1      3000000               1234     5000
    event 1      2000000               1034     4000
    event 1      1550000                834     2250
```

etc.

I've been able to figure out how to do the count a number of ways but haven't been able to figure out a way to implement the data into a table in the view in a way that won't croak the browser with a huge request.

Any input/feedback is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For a huge amount of datas, you should consider using DataTables with the server-side processing feature : http://datatables.net/usage/server-side